# Difference between -Tlinker.ld vs linker.ld in an makefile

Tags: c, makefile, linker-scripts

I have this linker.ld where I want to remapped ram.

```
MEMORY
  {
    ram (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 8M
  }
```

What is the difference between adding the linker like this:

```
sparc-gaisler-elf-gcc -O2 -std=c99 linker.ld -Ttext=0x80000000 -o main.o
```

vs.

```
sparc-gaisler-elf-gcc -O2 -std=c99 -Tlinker.ld -Ttext=0x80000000 -o main.o
```

The first one I get an warning:

```
redeclaration of memory region
```

and the second one, I get

```
no memory region specified for loadable section .data
```

I don't really understand what is the difference in how -T<linker_file> and just adding <linker_file> directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple.

With `-T` you replace the default linker script, without both will be used.

1. Fist case both are used and both define the same memory region
2. Second case - your linker script is far too trivial and misses all section definitions.